# Is there a way to batch split a file by chapter with ffmpeg and then reassemble with mkvmerge in windows?

Tags: json, ffmpeg, jq, trim, mkv

So I made a batch script originally with the ability to relatively precision trim a video into chapters without having to run by keyframes, but the code looks horrible and I can't get it to loop through all mp4 files nor get mkvmerge to append the files after splitting them. Code is below but be gentle it is my first try.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

REM CODE BELOW CREATES JSON FILES FOR ALL MP4 FILES WITHIN THE SAME DIRECTORY
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_chapters -loglevel error "01x01.mp4" > "01x01.json"

REM CODE BELOW SETS VARIABLES FROM EACH SPECIFIC JSON
FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('jq .chapters[2].start ^< 01x01.json') DO SET /A start1=%%i
FOR /F "delims=" %%j in ('jq .chapters[2].end ^< 01x01.json') DO SET /A end1=%%j

FOR /F "delims=" %%k in ('jq .chapters[4].start ^< 01x01.json') DO SET /A start2=%%k
FOR /F "delims=" %%l in ('jq .chapters[4].end ^< 01x01.json') DO SET /A end2=%%l

FOR /F "delims=" %%m in ('jq .chapters[6].start ^< 01x01.json') DO SET /A start3=%%m
FOR /F "delims=" %%n in ('jq .chapters[6].end ^< 01x01.json') DO SET /A end3=%%n

FOR /F "delims=" %%o in ('jq .chapters[8].start ^< 01x01.json') DO SET /A start4=%%o
FOR /F "delims=" %%p in ('jq .chapters[8].end ^< 01x01.json') DO SET /A end4=%%p

REM SETS THE DURATION OF EACH FILE TO USE PRECISION TIMING FOR START AND STOP TIMES
CALL vbs (%end1%-%start1%)/1000
SET duration1=%val%
CALL vbs (%end2%-%start2%)/1000
SET duration2=%val%
CALL vbs (%end3%-%start3%)/1000
SET duration3=%val%
CALL vbs (%end4%-%start4%)/1000
SET duration4=%val%

REM SETS THE START TIME IN SECONDS VS MILLISECONDS
CALL vbs (%start1%)/1000
SET start1=%val%
CALL vbs (%start2%)/1000
SET start2=%val%
CALL vbs (%start3%)/1000
SET start3=%val%
CALL vbs (%start4%)/1000
SET start4=%val%

REM TRIM AND SPLIT ORIGINAL FILE INTO SEPERATE SECTIONS BASED ON CHAPTER MARKERS
ffmpeg -ss %START1% -i 01x01.mp4 -ss 0 -c copy -to %DURATION1% -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-1.mp4
ffmpeg -ss %START2% -i 01x01.mp4 -ss 0 -c copy -to %DURATION2% -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-2.mp4
ffmpeg -ss %START3% -i 01x01.mp4 -ss 0 -c copy -to %DURATION3% -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-3.mp4
ffmpeg -ss %START4% -i 01x01.mp4 -ss 0 -c copy -to %DURATION4% -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-4.mp4

REM DELETES UNNEEDED JSON AFTER USE
del /s *.json

REM APPEND ALL MP4 FILES INTO COHESIVE MKV
for /d /r %%D in (*) do (
    pushd %%D
    set files=
    for %%F in (*.mp4) do set files=!files! + ^( "%%F" ^)
    if not "!files!"=="" %mkvmerge% -o "01x01-FINAL.mkv" !files:~2!
    popd
)

REM DELETE UNNEEDED MP4 ORIGINALS AND SPLIT FILES
del /s *.mp4
```

I know it is super long and every time I try to use a variable or a loop to run  through all files it can't read the json file. I've been at this all day and I can use the script as is but I have to make a file for each iteration.

I was also hoping to be able to have it only pull chapters labeled as "video" but I haven't quite figured that one out yet.

I'll add the vbs batch file for the arithmetic section as well as the sample json if it will help.

```
@echo off
>"%temp%\VBS.vbs" echo Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") : Wscript.echo (%*)
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\VBS.vbs"') do set "val=%%a"
del "%temp%\VBS.vbs"
```

```
{
    "chapters": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "end": 5590,
            "end_time": "5.590000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Video"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 5590,
            "start_time": "5.590000",
            "end": 13994,
            "end_time": "13.994000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Advertisement"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 13994,
            "start_time": "13.994000",
            "end": 163964,
            "end_time": "163.964000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Video"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 163964,
            "start_time": "163.964000",
            "end": 195940,
            "end_time": "195.940000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Advertisement"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 195940,
            "start_time": "195.940000",
            "end": 547849,
            "end_time": "547.849000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Video"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 547849,
            "start_time": "547.849000",
            "end": 595850,
            "end_time": "595.850000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Advertisement"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 595850,
            "start_time": "595.850000",
            "end": 1413588,
            "end_time": "1413.588000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Video"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 1413588,
            "start_time": "1413.588000",
            "end": 1477569,
            "end_time": "1477.569000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Advertisement"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "time_base": "1/1000",
            "start": 1477569,
            "start_time": "1477.569000",
            "end": 1529696,
            "end_time": "1529.696000",
            "tags": {
                "title": "Video"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I also tried using the start_time so I didn't have to do extra calculations but jq didn't like that either.

mkvmerge doesn't even try to run when I have it in here and I still need to cut 7 seconds off the end and 12 seconds off the front of it once it is all one file again.

Any help would be appreciated, I know it's a lot but I seem to have hit a roadblock or just sleep deprived at this point.

**UPDATE**

This works amazing I just need to figure out how to use files with spaces and I'm all set. I guess I could run a batch before hand replacing all spaces with underscores. That would probably work but I would like to not change filenames if I can help it.

```
@echo off

for %%i in (*.mp4) do (
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_chapters -loglevel error "%%i" ^| xidel - -se "$json/(chapters)()[id!=0 and tags/title='Video']/concat('ffmpeg -ss ',start div 1000,' -i %%i -to ',((end - start) div 1000),' -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero %%~ni-',position(),'.mp4')"') DO %%A
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('xidel -s --xquery "concat('mkvmerge -o &quot;%%~ni-FINAL.mkv&quot; &quot;',join(file:list(.,false(),'%%~ni-*.mp4'),'&quot; + &quot;'),'&quot;')"') DO %%A
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove the "*Advertisement*"-chapters.
This could probably be done entirely with `ffmpeg`, but without the source video I can't say for sure.

Anyway, let me offer you a very elegant solution for the splitting procedure with the help of [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

First of all, you don't have to save `ffprobe`'s output to a JSON-file. You can just pipe it to `xidel`:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_chapters -loglevel error "01x01.mp4" | xidel - -se "$json"
```

Select the objects/chapters labeled as "Video":

```
ffprobe [...] | xidel - -se "$json/(chapters)()[id!=0 and tags/title='Video']"
{
  "id": 2,
  "time_base": "1/1000",
  "start": 13994,
  "start_time": "13.994000",
  "end": 163964,
  "end_time": "163.964000",
  "tags": {
    "title": "Video"
  }
}
[...]
{
  "id": 8,
  "time_base": "1/1000",
  "start": 1477569,
  "start_time": "1477.569000",
  "end": 1529696,
  "end_time": "1529.696000",
  "tags": {
    "title": "Video"
  }
}
```

*(I'm not sure why you don't want the first chapter. If you do, then just remove* `id!=0 and`*.)*

To calculate the duration of the 4 chapters:

```
ffprobe [...] | xidel - -se "$json/(chapters)()[id!=0 and tags/title='Video']/round-half-to-even(end_time - start_time,3)"
#or
ffprobe [...] | xidel - -se "$json/(chapters)()[id!=0 and tags/title='Video']/((end - start) div 1000)"
149.97
351.909
817.738
52.127
```

Create the `ffmpeg` strings/commands with these values and `start`:

```
ffprobe [...] | xidel - -se "$json/(chapters)()[id!=0 and tags/title='Video']/concat('ffmpeg -ss ',start div 1000,' -i 01x01.mp4 -to ',((end - start) div 1000),' -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-',position(),'.mp4')"
ffmpeg -ss 13.994 -i 01x01.mp4 -to 149.97 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-1.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 195.94 -i 01x01.mp4 -to 351.909 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-2.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 595.85 -i 01x01.mp4 -to 817.738 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-3.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 1477.569 -i 01x01.mp4 -to 52.127 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-4.mp4
```

Prettified command/query:

```
ffprobe [...] | xidel - -se ^"^
  $json/(chapters)()[id!=0 and tags/title='Video']/concat(^
    'ffmpeg -ss ',^
    start div 1000,^
    ' -i 01x01.mp4 -to ',^
    ((end - start) div 1000),^
    ' -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-',^
    position(),^
    '.mp4'^
  )^
"
```

To execute these `ffmpeg` commands simply put the entire `ffprobe`/`xidel` command in a `FOR`-loop:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('ffprobe [...] ^| xidel - -se "$json/(chapters)()[id!=0 and tags/title='Video']/concat('ffmpeg -ss ',start div 1000,' -i 01x01.mp4 -to ',((end - start) div 1000),' -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero 01x01-',position(),'.mp4')"') DO %A
```

*(Within a Batch-script use* `%%A` *and in case of* `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` *escape the exclamationmarks;* `id^!=0`*)*

With all of `cmd`'s shortcomings I would again use `xidel` to create the `mkvmerge` string/command:

```
xidel -s -e "file:list(.,false(),'01x01-*.mp4')"
01x01-1.mp4
01x01-2.mp4
01x01-3.mp4
01x01-4.mp4

xidel -s -e "join(file:list(.,false(),'01x01-*.mp4'),' + ')"
01x01-1.mp4 + 01x01-2.mp4 + 01x01-3.mp4 + 01x01-4.mp4

xidel -s -e "concat('\"',join(file:list(.,false(),'01x01-*.mp4'),'\" + \"'),'\"')"
#or
xidel -s --xquery "concat('&quot;',join(file:list(.,false(),'01x01-*.mp4'),'&quot; + &quot;'),'&quot;')"
"01x01-1.mp4" + "01x01-2.mp4" + "01x01-3.mp4" + "01x01-4.mp4"

xidel -s --xquery "concat('mkvmerge -o &quot;01x01-FINAL.mkv&quot; &quot;',join(file:list(.,false(),'01x01-*.mp4'),'&quot; + &quot;'),'&quot;')"
mkvmerge -o "01x01-FINAL.mkv" "01x01-1.mp4" + "01x01-2.mp4" + "01x01-3.mp4" + "01x01-4.mp4"
```

To execute the `mkvmerge` command again simply put the entire `xidel` command in a `FOR`-loop:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s --xquery "concat('mkvmerge -o &quot;01x01-FINAL.mkv&quot; &quot;',join(file:list(.,false(),'01x01-*.mp4'),'&quot; + &quot;'),'&quot;')"') DO %A
```

*(Why* `--xquery` *and* `&quot;`*? Because* `\"` *will cause "escape-character-hell" in a* `FOR`*-loop)*

If you use just these two `FOR`-loops, it also means that `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: This only creates the very first chapter, which I don't want, but taking out the `id!=0 and` did create all chapters. Which I guess is fine. And I also got the mkvmerge to work, but it is including the original file that was separated as well.

Comment: This is perfect and works for anything that doesn't have spaces. If I try filenames with spaces the first for loop breaks but I've tried adding in `&quot;` in a few places but that also results in breaking the first for loop. I'll keep at it and see if I can get it working for filenames with spaces. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Sipherdrakon Try `for %%i in ("*.mp4") do (`.

Comment: It is still splitting it into two file names, but no biggie. Just added a snippet to change all spaces to underscores and it ran perfectly.